# ActionScript 3.0 To Send POST and get data from .Net 4 using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, actionscript

I am trying to get my flash application to send a request back to the webserver so that it can get some information. So far after reading on stackoverflow for a while and on the net I have some code written, but its not quite working right. I need just a little help tying it all together.

Here is the controller for my webserver

```
    //
    // POST: /Home/HoneyPot
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HoneyPot(bool GetData)
    {
        //ViewBag.
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the ActionScript code that is supposed to be making the request.

```
// get dynamic page element information
var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:59418/HoneyPot");
myData.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

vars.Input = "GetData=true";

myData.data = vars;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotPostData_Spiral);
loader.load(myData);

function gotPostData_Spiral(anEvent:Event):void
{
    var postData = anEvent.target.data.myVar;
}
```

Right now when I run the flash code I get this output back:

> Error opening URL 'http://localhost:59418/HoneyPot'
>
> Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query
>   string containing name/value pairs.
>
> at Error$/throwError()
>
> at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
>
> at flash.net::URLVariables()
>
> at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
vars.Input = "GetData=true";
```

try:

```
vars.GetData = "true";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I tried that and got back this message from adobe:

Error opening URL 'http://localhost:59418/HoneyPot'
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
 at flash.net::URLVariables()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()